# Make MapAnnotation slide to new location with animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, mapkit

I want to want to slide the annotation over map to new position when coordinates are received. And the change each time coordinates are changed.

This is view I am using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var request = Requests()
@State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 56.946285, longitude: 24.105078), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: request.users){ user in
        withAnimation(.linear){
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: user.latitude, longitude: user.longitude)) {
                AnnotationView(requests: request, user: user)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnnotationView: View{
    @ObservedObject var requests: Requests
    @State private var showDetails = false
    let user: User
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            if showDetails{
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 50)
                        .overlay{
                            VStack{
                                Text(user.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .font(.title3)
                                Text(user.address)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                        .offset(y: -50)
                }
            }
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: user.image)) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .scaledToFit()
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showDetails.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And in view model I have a function that work over incoming data. The response is just received data from server.

@Published var users = User

```
 func collectUsers(_ response: String){
    if users.count != 0{
        var data = response.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        data.removeLast()
        
        for newData in data{
            var components = newData.components(separatedBy: ",")
            var userID = components[0].components(separatedBy: " ")
            userID.removeFirst()
            components[0] = userID[0]
            
            if let index = self.users.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == Int(components[0]) }){
                self.getAddress(latitude: Double(components[1])!, longitude: Double(components[2])!) { address in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users[index].address = address
                        self.users[index].latitude = Double(components[1])!
                        self.users[index].longitude = Double(components[2])!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        var userData = response.components(separatedBy: ";")
        userData.removeLast()
        
        let users = userData.compactMap { userString -> User? in
            let userProperties = userString.components(separatedBy: ",")
            
            var idPart = userProperties[0].components(separatedBy: " ")
            if idPart.count == 2{
                idPart.removeFirst()
            }
            
            guard userProperties.count == 5 else { return nil }
            guard let id = Int(idPart[0]),
                  let latitude = Double(userProperties[3]),
                  let longitude = Double(userProperties[4]) else { return nil }
            
            var collectedUser = User(id: id, name: userProperties[1], image: userProperties[2], latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, address: "")
           
            return collectedUser
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.users = users
        }
    }
}

func getAddress(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]
            if let thoroughfare = placemark?.thoroughfare, let subThoroughfare = placemark?.subThoroughfare {
                let collectedAddress = thoroughfare + subThoroughfare
                completion(collectedAddress)
            }
        } else {
            print("Could not get address \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And also I dont understand why calling getAdress does not invoke changes on view each time coordinates are received.

Comment: WithAnimation is a function block not a view builder. The “.animation” view modifier would be better there. Not perfect because Map is full of its own animations but likely a little better.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it didnt work